# SQL: Select inside select?

Tags: sql

I have a table of car accident in a major city, and the structure is like:

accident_table has the following columns:

```
id, caseno, date_of_occurrence, street, iucr, primary_type,
description, district, community_area, year, updated_on
```

I want to write a query that finds the street which has the most accidents for each district(I think the street count for each street is the number of accident that happened on that street).

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (street) 
   street, 
   district
FROM
(
  SELECT
    count(street) as street_cnt,
    street,
    district
  FROM accident_table
)
WHERE street_count = (SELECT max(street_cnt))
```

It did not give me syntax error, but timed out, so I guess it took too long to run.

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: What Relational Database Management Software are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Also, please provide information about the key columns and indexes

Comment: `street_count = (SELECT max(street_cnt))` definitely doesn't make sense, the column name is wrong for a start. You probably just need `order by street_cnt limit 1` no `distinct`. Also you probably want `sum` not `count`.

Comment: It is weird that you don't get a syntax error, because the subquery `SELECT count(street), street, district FROM accident_table` is invalid. You cannot aggregate and not aggregate thus at the same time. Either you'd have to add `GROUP BY street, district` or use aggregation functions on the two columns.

Comment: The rest of your query is valid, but makes no sense. `DISTINCT ON` is PostgreSQL and you'd use `ORDER BY` to tell the DBMS for which rows to decide. `DISTINCT ON (street)` makes no sense anyway, because you don't want a result row per street, but per district. And `WHERE street_cnt = (SELECT max(street_cnt))` is the same as `WHERE street_cnt = (SELECT street_cnt)` which is the same as `WHERE street_cnt = street_cnt` It compares a value to itself and has no effect on the selected data.

Comment: Be aware that there can be two or more streets for a district having the same top number of accidents. sticky bit shows how to deal with this in their answer. PostgreSQL's `ON DISTINCT` (as shown in Gordon's answer) does not handle ties, but just picks one of the top streets per district arbitrarily.

Comment: And as Stuart Ainsworth has mentioned: It is important with SQL questions to tell us which DBMS you are using. `DISTINCT ON` looks like PostgreSQL. Is this your DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate to get the count of accidents for each street. Then use the `rank()` window function to rank the streets within a district by the count of accidents in them. Then only select the ones that were ranked at the top.

```
SELECT x.district,
       x.street,
       x.accidents
       FROM (SELECT a.district,
                    a.street,
                    count(*) accidents,
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a.district
                                 ORDER BY count(*) DESC) r
                    FROM accident_table a
                    GROUP BY a.district,
                             a.street) x
       WHERE x.r = 1;
```

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `order by x.accidents limit 1`? And you should add a note of the difference between `rank` and `row_number` (ties)

Comment: @Charlieface: That it only outputs the (*one*) street (in whatever district) with the most accidents *overall*. But the OP stated they "want to ... find[s] the street which has the most accidents for **each** district" (emphasis: me).

Comment: Sorry missed that. My point on `row_number` stands

Comment: Thanks guys, all the queries worked for me. It took me a while to reply as I had to get the results output on a map using Python. So I had to loop through the districts then run the queries for each districts. I forgot to select distinct for the districts and it took too long to run as most of the runs were doing the same thing as they were for the same district. After using distinct districts, it works well. Thanks all again!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like Postgres.  In that database, you can express this without a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.district)
       a.district, a.street, COUNT(*) as accidents
FROM accident_table a
GROUP BY a.district, a.street
ORDER BY a.district, COUNT(*) DESC;
```

That said, your problem is performance, which is probably not affected by subqueries.  An index on `accident_table(district, street)` might help performance.